# iOS in-app purchase free / paid persistence

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am building a game that will be free to play, and will include 100 free consumable 'hints'.  I intend to offer more hints for purchase through in-app purchase.  My current method is to store a file locally with the number of hints the user still has left.  When the game is first downloaded the local file doesn't exist, so a new file is created with 100 hints.  When an in-app purchase happens, it simply adds to the number of hints. (In the game, each hint simply removes a choice from a multiple choice question - the file simply stores a counter.)

My problem: A user could simply delete the app when they have 0 hints remaining (which will delete my local file that has a count of 0), re-download the app from the app store and they will then start again with 100 hints.

My question: How do I prevent this?  Is there a different method I should use for storing hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the Keychain to store your data, because the Keychain items are not deleted even if the app is Uninstalled or removed. This Api will help a lot [link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore), have a look

or

You can refer to Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW30) on Keychain data

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to offer some part of your hints as an in-app product, I suggest you to keep track of all your hints (both purchased and free) on a server. This way you can keep track of each user and even if they delete and re-download your app, you will still be able to keep track of your hints.

**Edit:** If you are implementing IAP you might find it healthy to keep track of your purchased goods anyway (ie. keeping track of your purchase statistics, watching out for fake in-app purchases, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

usualy you use a server for such things, so not the device but the account is the interesting. Also a good possibility to save your progress and share to other devices ;)